# PHP - echo and fgets weird characters

Tags: php, fgets

I'm trying to display the content of a text file on my website using PHP's `fgets`, but when I `echo` the lines in combination with something else (`<br>`, `\n`, ...) I get pretty weird characters.

Here's my code :

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8');

$handle = @fopen("test.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
        echo $buffer."<br>";
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Here is the content of `test.txt` :

```
1
2
3
4
5
... (6 - 18)
19
20
```

And here's what I get :

> **Result with `<br>`**

[image]

If I use `\n` instead of `<br>`, I don't even get Chinese characters :

> **Result with `\n`**

[image]

I think the issue comes from `fgets()`, because when I print only one line (without the loop) I get the same issue, but if replace `$buffer` by `"1"` (`echo "1"."<br>";`) I get the expected result.

## EDIT

As suggested I modified the code to add `header('Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8');` at the beginning of the php file, and modified the output as well.

Comment: This may be a dumb question but is there chinese text in `test.txt`?...

Comment: `header('Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8');` add this line in the top of php code

Comment: Here is a little article that might help you http://kunststube.net/frontback/

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar Doing so change the size of the characters, but doesn't resolve the problem (with `\n` I also get a new line linebreak, but the characters are sill there).

Comment: can you update your question with your `.text` file text.

Comment: @N.Cornet I try on my text `<br>` and `\n` both working fine !!!

Comment: @N.Cornet .. Both is Working ..!!

Comment: I know that it should be working (that's why it works with you) but I still get this issue.

Comment: Just tried creating the file with another text editor (Sublime Text instead of TextEdit) and I get the same thing as you, I'll search again what's wrong in TextEdit preferences... Thank you anyway.

Comment: ok then problem with creating txt file

Comment: @N.Cornet .. avoid to use `break` like this `<br>` .. Please. Use Like this `</br>` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the issue must be somewhere in the text file : I created a new one  and the issue was gone.

I don't know the original encryption of the file because a friend gave it to me.

I'll update this answer if I find out exactly what was going on.

## EDIT

I made a copy via TextEdit and when saving it the default encoding format was UTF-16, I guess that was the problem.

Comment: Yes When You Create an New Text File `default` encoding format is `UTF-16` So That Was The Reason you get the Character Sets encoded !!

Answer (score 0):

> **Working DEMO:** http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/xrsk-a0uv
>
> **Text File::**  http://m.uploadedit.com/ba3s/1500405331493.txt
>
> **Problem:** at the Time of create text file it's select the encoding format is `UTF-16.` !! `UTF-8` `by default for nodepad,nodepad++,sublime etc..` !!

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8');

$handle = @fopen("http://m.uploadedit.com/ba3s/1500405331493.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($buffer = fgets($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
        echo $buffer."</br>";
    }
    if (!feof($handle)) {
        echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

?>
```

---

> **NOTE:** Add header for `charset-utf-8`

`header('Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8');`

> **`OUTPUT` Using With `"\n"`**

[image]

> **`OUTPUT` Using With `"</br>"`**

[image]